# Jpa Group By Query Returning Map<Enum, List<Bean>>

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

Hello.

I am trying to accomplish to create a group by query using EclipseLink JPA in the following scenario:

emum BeanType
class BeanParam { id, beanType, @ManyToOne param }

enum ParamType
class Param { id, name, paramType, foo, bar }

I wish to query for a Map of <ParamType, List<Param>>, by a BeanType, meaning the Parameters attached to that BeanType grouped by its paramTypes.

How would you guys make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would first execute a JPQL query:

```
select distinct param from BeanParam beanParam
inner join beanParam.param param
where beanParam.beanType = :beanType
```

Then I would iterate through the `List<Param>` returned, and group them by paramType. With Guava, it would be:

```
ListMultimap<ParamType, Param> m = ArrayListMultimap.create();
for (Param param : params) {
    m.put(param.getParamType(), param);
}
```